# How do I color a string of text RED in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, greasemonkey

How can I write a simple Greasemonkey script that allows it to search for a string of text on one website and then simply color it red?

For example, say a site had the words, "Normal Healthy (R11-0902 Gr 9)" ... could we program this script to make all instances of this turn red? I would edit the script often to add additional strings to turn red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will highlight all the `Greasmonkey` in this page.

```
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Greasemonkey/g, function(m){
    return '<span style="background-color:yellow">'+m+'</span>'
});
```

In your case the pattern would be something like `/\w+ \w+ \(\w\d\d-\d{4} \w\w \d\)/`. This will only work if your format of the word (*Normal Healthy (R11-0902 Gr 9)*) is consistent.

Other formats can be,

1. ```
   /\w+ \w+\([^\)]+\)/
   ```
2. ```
   /\w+ \w+\([^\s\w\d]+\)/
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot! I am attempting to expand your script to make it more powerful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982891/small-greasemonkey-script-that-highlights-h2-elements - Please feel free to take a look, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Changing the whole page's `innerHTML` (!!!) will trash event handlers.  Also, when "Greasemonkey" inevitably changes to something real, you will get [the nightmare of mixing regex and HTML/JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/331508).

Comment: Well if you or anyone has any suggestions for the link I posted in my last comment, I'm all ears and do appreciate your advice.